# Laravel/SQL sort by popularity/trending

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a website with images, and images can have tags. Many images can also have the same tag. So 2 images can have the tag "painting".

I have an `images` table, a `tags` table, and a an `images_tag` pivot table.

The `images_tag` table has the columns: `id`, `images_id`, `tag_id`, and `created_at`.

What I want is to be able to essentially to find which tags are trending, within, say, the last 72 hours.

This means I want to have a query that takes all the tags used in the past 72 hours

```
$trendingTags = ImagesTag::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(72))
```

and takes, say, the top 3 most used tags. So in this case

```
$trendingTags = ImagesTag::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(72))
->orderBy('tag_id most frequently used', 'desc')
->take(3);
```

How could I make this work?

**Edit:**

In response to fubar's answer, I tried the following:

Controller:

```
$trendingTags = Tag::selectRaw('tags.*, COUNT(image_tag.id) AS count')
->join('image_tag', 'tags.id', '=', 'image_tag.tag_id')
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(72))
->orderBy('count', 'desc')
->take(3);

return view('home')
>with('trendingTags', $trendingTags)
```

This gave me the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'commendme.image_tag' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate
>   from `tags` inner join `image_tag` on `tags`.`id` =
>   `image_tag`.`tag_id` where `created_at` >= 2017-06-16 02:44:02 order
>   by `count` desc limit 3)

So I tried switching the code to reflect the images_tag table (rather than image_tag, which I'm guessing is a typo on fubar's part), and I got another error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in
>   'order clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tags` inner
>   join `images_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `images_tag`.`tag_id` where
>   `created_at` >= 2017-06-16 02:45:15 order by `count` desc limit 3)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\series\commend-me\CommendMe\resources\views\home.blade.php)

**EDIT 2:**

New error after trying out fubar's last edit:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image_count'
>   in 'order clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `tags` inner
>   join `images_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `images_tag`.`tag_id` where
>   `created_at` >= 2017-06-16 02:55:17 group by `tags`.`id` order by
>   `image_count` desc limit 3) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\series\commend-me\CommendMe\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Comment: You are getting error `unknown column 'image_count'` because you have forgotten to rename alias so change this in your query: `COUNT(images_tag.id) AS image_count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing from your explanation that you actually want the `Tag` models themselves, rather than the pivot data.

If so, then you need to join the `tags` table to the `image_tag` table, and then count the number relationships between the `images` and `tags` tables. Once you have this value, simply order by it.

```
$trendingTags = Tag::selectRaw('tags.*, COUNT(images_tag.id) AS image_count')
    ->join('images_tag', 'tags.id', '=', 'images_tag.tag_id')
    ->where('images_tag.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours(72))
    ->groupBy('tags.id')
    ->orderBy('image_count', 'desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

**Edit**

In response to the errors posted by OP.

I noticed that the join table I referenced is actually called `images_tag`, not `image_tag`. OP, it's a Laravel standard to use singular names of the relations in alphabetical order when naming pivot tables. I have however modified my answer.

I also noticed that I had missed the important `groupBy` statement, which is required by `SQL` aggregator functions.

Finally, I have renamed `count` to `image_count`, in case MySQL considers this a reserved word.

**Edit #2**

I've just tested this in one of my projects, and it worked as expected.

```
$categories = FaqCategory::selectRaw('faq_categories.*, COUNT(faq_faq_category.id) AS faq_count')
    ->join('faq_faq_category', 'faq_categories.id', '=', 'faq_faq_category.faq_category_id')
    ->groupBy('faq_categories.id')
    ->orderBy('faq_count', 'desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately your code is giving me some errors. I've edited the main post to show these errors.

Comment: Tried it. Another error. Edited the main post again.

Comment: I've added the missing `get()` call at the end of the `Builder`, but other than that, this works for me. You may wish to update your question with specific Laravel, PHP and MySQL versions.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I was also looking into whether or not the `withCount` method would have helped here, but no matter now.